# Что означает эта надпись - не могут же одновременно выполняться и Да и НЕТ

Tags: java

```
while (reply != 'y' && reply != 'n');
```

Comment: Пока reply не равно ни y, ни n. Проверяется на неравенство. Например, продолжать требовать ввод с клавиатуры, пока не введут y или n.

Comment: Смущает точка с запятой в конце. Если у цикла нет тела, то он либо будет бесконечным, либо не отработает ни разу в зависимости от значения в `reply`.

Comment: По правилу ДеМоргана можно условие цика преобразовать в `!(reply == 'y || reply == 'n')`. И так будет понятнее объяснение @hinotf.

Comment: Кроме `да` и `нет` есть `может быть`:) Так вот - эта надпись означает `до тех пор пока` `может быть`

Comment: @Vladimir вероятно переменная `reply` изменяется в параллельном потоке

Comment: @Vladimir - вероятно, это цикл `do - while`.

Answer (score 2):

Не могут одновременно выполнятся, но могут одновременно НЕ выполнятся. Именно неравенство проверяет оператор `!=`.

Answer (score 1):

Тут в цикле while у тебя выполняется проверка на неравенство reply на 'y' и 'n'.
Почему одновременно ДА и НЕТ, если у тебя работает оператор И? Пока обе части не выполнятся, то есть пока у тебя получается while(true && true), соответственно будет выполняться цикл.